# Mysql complex sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a query like this

```
SELECT videos.*, 
       (SELECT COUNT(comment_id) 
        FROM comments 
        WHERE comments.comments_video_id = videos.id) AS video_comments
FROM videos
ORDER BY video_comments DESC
```

Now if I have 2 rows with the same 'videos_comments' count, how can write this so that between these 2 videos, the one which had the latest comment (comments_date) in the comments table is displayed first

Comment: Simply use the comment_Date in ORDER BY with DESC and you can also use comment_date in GROUP by so that you will get only one record by comment_date

Comment: @GaganUpadhyay thanks for fast reply, any chance of example code, I am fairly new to mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT videos.id, count(*) video_comments 
FROM videos LEFT JOIN comments 
ON comments.comments_video_id = videos.id
GROUP BY videos.id
ORDER BY video_comments DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT videos.id, 
       MAX(comments_date) as latest_comment, 
       COUNT(*) as video_comments 
FROM videos 
LEFT JOIN comments 
       ON comments.comments_video_id = videos.id
GROUP BY videos.id
ORDER BY 
      video_comments,   
      latest_comment
```

If you want video.*

```
SELECT videos.*,
       video_comments,   
       latest_comment 
FROM videos
JOIN (
        SELECT videos.id, 
               MAX(comments_date) as latest_comment, 
               COUNT(*) as video_comments 
        FROM videos 
        LEFT JOIN comments 
               ON comments.comments_video_id = videos.id
        GROUP BY videos.id

      ) T
   ON videos.video_id = T.video_id
ORDER BY 
      video_comments,   
      latest_comment
```